# Postfix won't accept SASL logins

Tags: email, postfix, smtp

I've followed [this guide](http://flurdy.com/docs/postfix/) to setup an email server with IMAP and SMTP. IMAP is working great, but SMTP doesn't work.

If I try to send a message using telnet:

```
MAIL FROM: <tom@xxxxxxxx.com>
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO: <a@example.com>
554 5.7.1 <a@example.com>: Relay access denied
```

Attempting to login with my mail client (Mail.app on OS X Lion) gives this error in the system log:

```
postfix/smtpd[13322]: warning: my.computer.hostname[12.34.56.78]: SASL PLAIN authentication failed: no mechanism available
```

The client says "The server rejected the password given."

What can I do to get email relaying working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was related to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cyrus-sasl2/+bug/875440). Following the temporary solution steps (downgrading temporarily) provided a fix. Hopefully the bug will be fixed soon and I'll be able to upgrade.